# How Do I Reply?

Tags: support

I posted a question here and I got an answer. I would like to reply to that answer. How do I do that? There is a comment button but it allows only a short reply. Mine is a little longer. Where is the Reply button?

Comment: The reason there's no reply is because you're not supposed to reply; work on adding the information to your question!

Comment: If you have to just add two comments. I do it quite often.

Comment: If you can't add a comment to their post, add it to yours and put an @personyouwanttoreplyto

Answer (score 1):

You can submit comments to any answer to any of your own questions. Just press the "add comment" button. This is not a forum, so there's no reply button.

[image]

Try to avoid "thanks" comments and such. For that there's the "accept" (green) button and upvote. More information in the [Help Center](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)